# Increment numbers by time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to set up a simple number counter that provides some fun stats.

- The counter has to:
- Only count when in viewport - Done
- Count numbers - Done
- Automatically update the numbers every month by a certain amount.

I'm having problems with the last one.

What I want to do is have the functionality to increase the number of that particular stat independently, every month.

For example:

```
        <div class="stat col-lg-2">
            <p class="counter red-bull">4246</p> <!-- Plus 132 every month -->
            <p class="counter-name">Cans of red bull</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stat col-lg-2">
            <p class="counter ping-pong">7624</p> <!-- Plus 215 every month --> 
            <p class="counter-name">Games of ping pong</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stat col-lg-2">
            <p class="counter fifa">635</p> <!-- Plus 46 every month -->
            <p class="counter-name">Hours of FIFA</p>
        </div>
```

I wouldn't have a clue how to go about this, my knowledge of the `date()` function is very limited also.

I've got a fiddle up of my existing code.

http://jsfiddle.net/patadvis/csk88vfc/

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something a lot more suited for the serverside, where you actually have a reliable clock and a way to keep the numbers between sessions and users.

Comment: You cannot guarantee the stats by using the user's date.  Do as @adeneo said, calculate the date server-side and return the results to the user.

Comment: I've got little to no knowledge in PHP (using Wordpress), do you know what i'd write if I were to do this server side? @adeneo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own simple JavaScript function, here it is:

```
function updateCounters() {
    var START_DATE = new Date(2014, 7, 8), // start date (e.g. today)
        // I typed in "7" because in JS months start from 0
        // edit the date if you want to see a change
        ONE_MONTH = 2592000000, // one month in milliseconds
        MONTHS = parseInt((new Date() - START_DATE) / ONE_MONTH);

    $('.red-bull').html(parseInt($('.red-bull').html()) + MONTHS * 132);
    $('.ping-pong').html(parseInt($('.ping-pong').html()) + MONTHS * 215);
    $('.fifa').html(parseInt($('.fifa').html()) + MONTHS * 46);
}

updateCounters();
```

The above function will automatically update the values **every month**.

WORKING EXAMPLE: **http://jsfiddle.net/MeBeiM/csk88vfc/4/**

If you want to update on the first of every month, then you only will have to change the first line inside the function to:

```
var START_DATE = new Date(2014, 7, 1); // first august 2014
```

---

If you want to update the values **gradually during the month** you can make some little changes to the function, here it is:

```
function updateCounters() {
    var START_DATE = new Date(2014, 7, 8), // start date (e.g. today)
        // I typed in "7" because in JS months start from 0
        // edit the date if you want to see a change
        ONE_MONTH = 2592000000, // one month in milliseconds
        MONTHS = (new Date() - START_DATE) / ONE_MONTH;

    $('.red-bull').html(parseInt($('.red-bull').html()) + parseInt(MONTHS * 132));
    $('.ping-pong').html(parseInt($('.ping-pong').html()) + parseInt(MONTHS * 215));
    $('.fifa').html(parseInt($('.fifa').html()) + parseInt(MONTHS * 46));
}

updateCounters();
```

WORKING EXAMPLE: **http://jsfiddle.net/MeBeiM/csk88vfc/5/**

**NOTE:** I removed the rest of your code because it has many errors and it stops the JavaScript causing my function to not work. You should check it out...

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to update these numbers on the server side. I'm assuming that you want to update the numbers every month since a certain date, perhaps the user's registration date. Here's one way that you could accomplish this in PHP:

```
    <?php 
        $registrationDate = $this->currentUser->registrationDate;
        //2592000 is approximate number of seconds in a month
        $monthsRegistered = (time() - $registrationDate)/2592000;
    ?>
    <div class="stat col-lg-2">
        <p class="counter red-bull"><?php echo 4246 + 132*$monthsRegistered?></p> <!-- Plus 132 every month -->
        <p class="counter-name">Cans of red bull</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stat col-lg-2">
        <p class="counter ping-pong"><?php echo 7624 + 215*$monthsRegistered ?></p> <!-- Plus 215 every month --> 
        <p class="counter-name">Games of ping pong</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stat col-lg-2">
        <p class="counter fifa">6<?php echo 35 + 46*$monthsRegistered ?></p> <!-- Plus 46 every month -->
        <p class="counter-name">Hours of FIFA</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: How would you go about refactoring this to update on the first of every month? @ckirksey3

Comment: Perhaps you could do something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416894/calculate-the-number-of-months-between-two-dates-in-php)? You'd need to modify it to only change on the first of the month.