# Calculate Months From two dates

Tags: php, date, datetime, monthcalendar

I need to calculate months from two dates

For example :

If `date1 = '2014-08-20'` means 20th Aug 2014

&  `date2 =  '2014-09-17'` means today date

then I need to difference of `months = 2 (Aug + September)`

Same way

```
     If `date1 = '2014-03-15'` means 15th March 2014

     &  `date2 =  '2014-09-17'`  means today date
```

then I need to difference of `months =  7 (March + April + May + June + July + Aug + SEPT)`

How can I do with php date functions ?

Comment: Please check, may be duplicate :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416894/calculate-the-number-of-months-between-two-dates-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for?

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2014-08-20');
$date2 = new DateTime('2014-09-17');

echo  $date2->format('n') - $date1->format('n') + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2014-08-20');
$date2 = new DateTime('2014-09-17');

$diff = $date2->diff($date1);

$diff->format('%m months');
```

Comment: it gives me 0 months; But I need as I said in question is months = 2

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take into account for each months passed, you could try this:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2014-03-15');
$date2 = new DateTime();
$date2->modify('last day of this month'); // adjust it to take into account
$int = new DateInterval('P1M'); // every month
$count = 0;
$range = new DatePeriod($date1, $int, $date2);
foreach($range as $d) {
    ++$count; // for each month incremenent
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: yes Casimir et Hippolyte has given very short answer so It will helpful to me & others also.Thanks to you again for your answer.

Comment: sure @SandipPatel glad i was able to help

Answer (score 0):

You can do with:

```
$first_date = '2014-03-15';
$second_date = '2014-09-17';

$date1 = strtotime($first_date);
$date2 = strtotime($second_date);

$year1 = date('Y', $date1);
$year2 = date('Y', $date2);

$month1 = date('m', $date1);
$month2 = date('m', $date2);

$diff = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);
```

But to count day difference also, we can do as follow:

```
$date_interval = $first_date->diff($second_date);
        echo "difference " . $date_interval->y . " years, " . $date_interval->m." months, ".$date_interval->d." days ";
```

Check this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312439/php-return-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-an-array/)

Comment: it gives me 6 months; But I need as I said in question is months = 7

Comment: so for that it should also count the day difference? yeah.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it in the following manner.

Consider this Example :

```
<?php
$start    = new DateTime('2011-12-02');
$start->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = new DateTime('2012-05-06');
$end->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $monthNum=$dt->format("m");
    echo $dt->format("Y").date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10)). PHP_EOL;
}
```

See in action [Here](http://3v4l.org/iQ0rQ)

Reference : [How to list all months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742998/how-to-list-all-months-between-two-dates)