# select stored mysql date and current date and compare it in months

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Actually i am creating recruitment portal in which the candidate cannot apply again in 3 months. After 3 months he/she can apply. so i need to know how to do this. when candidate fill up form, the form date is stored in mysql database using current time stamp. now i need to compare the current time and database time, if difference between both date is greater than 3 months then only values can be added to the database.
    In short the candidate cannot fill the form again in between 3 months. if the 3 months are completed then candidate can fill the form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the number of months between two dates in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416894/calculate-the-number-of-months-between-two-dates-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, in your database :

```
table name : candidates
fields : email, form_date, .... ( other fields )
where 'email' is the primary key and 'form_date' has the timestamp in which a candidate had filled the form last time successfully.
```

Then in your model : ( seeing your tag, I'm guessing you are using Codeigniter 3 )

```
    $query = "SELECT email FROM candidates WHERE form_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH";

    $queryResult = $this->db->query($query);

    foreach( $queryResult->result() as $row )
        $candidates_email = $row;
```

Now, you have the primary key in $candidates_email, you can update the candidate row with new information or do whatever you like :)

Comment: sorry but my primary key is candidate id, and still i don't get idea how to prevent same candidate to fill up form because his 3 months are not completed.

Comment: you can use a verified unique entity ( email or phone no., etc )  to represent each unique candidate.  Then search for that using the above query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some 'date math' in MySQL if you prefer. You didn't tell us what your table looks like but here's an example: SELECT ...., DATE_SUB(your_date_var, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) as SomeColName from YourTable WHERE.... So you can play around with this - and there's a DATE_ADD if you want to read their last apply day and add 3 months to it and compare to NOW(). Good luck.