# Calculate number of calendar months between two dates

Tags: php, date

I would like to calculate number of **calendar months** between two days. For example:

```
2017-11-01 => 2017-11-30 = 1 (the same month)
2017-11-01 => 2017-12-01 = 2 (two different calendar months in the date)
2017-11-30 => 2017-12-01 = 2 (the same as above)
2017-11-15 => 2018-06-01 = 8 (6 + 2 different calendar months in the date)
```

How can I do that? So far I have:

```
$monthStart = new DateTime('2017-11-01');
$monthEnd = new DateTime('2017-12-01');
$dateDiff = $monthStart->diff($monthEnd);
$maxMonths = ($dateDiff->m + ($dateDiff->y*12) + $dateDiff->d>0?1:0);
```

But it doesn't work for some dates.

This QUESTION IS DIFFERENT from: [Calculate the number of months between two dates in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416894/calculate-the-number-of-months-between-two-dates-in-php) as I want to calculate the month every time the number for month changes. Not only when there is a 30 days difference between two days. Check the examples I have provided.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416894/calculate-the-number-of-months-between-two-dates-in-php

Comment: It is not a duplicate, check the examples. I don't want 30 days difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = "2007-01-01";
$b = "2008-05-31";

$i = date("Ym", strtotime($a));
while($i <= date("Ym", strtotime($b))){
    echo $i."<br>";
    if(substr($i, 4, 2) == "12")
        $i = (date("Y", strtotime($i."01")) + 1)."01";
    else
        $i++;
}
```

output:

200701
200702
200703
200704
200705
200706
200707
200708
200709
200710
200711
200712
200801
200802
200803
200804
200805