# Is there any way to increment a number after every month in PHP

Tags: php, date

I'm working on a project in PHP. What i want to do is to increment a number (Like **500**) by itself **every month**. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Only possible way is to use cron jobs.

Comment: You could calculate the number of months between a hard-coded start date (day when you first release that feature) and the current date. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416894/calculate-the-number-of-months-between-two-dates-in-php

Comment: You can calculate that with an inception date and `DateTime::diff` to find the offset to now or some date.

Comment: @Jared Farrish, could you give an instance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact algorithm, but guessing the below:

```
$start = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$end = new DateTime('2010-12-23');

$diff = $end->diff($start);

$months = ($diff->y * 12) + $diff->m;
$rollup = 0;

var_dump("months: $months");

while ($months-- > 0) {
    echo "rollup: $rollup".PHP_EOL;
    $rollup += $rollup ?: 500;
}

var_dump("result: $rollup");
```

Gives:

```
string(10) "months: 14"
rollup: 0
rollup: 500
rollup: 1000
rollup: 2000
rollup: 4000
rollup: 8000
rollup: 16000
rollup: 32000
rollup: 64000
rollup: 128000
rollup: 256000
rollup: 512000
rollup: 1024000
rollup: 2048000
string(15) "result: 4096000"
```

https://3v4l.org/51XMD

Answer (score 0):

I've made few assumptions:

- you need this auto increment value somewhere in your code which will be executed as a part of some script
- your initial date and `500` value belong to the past, I mean any current date will be greater than that initial date

https://ideone.com/iobOZO

```
$initialDate = strtotime("2018-12-01");

$years = (date("Y") - date("Y", $initialDate));

$number = 500 + $years*12 
          + date("m") - date("m", $initialDate);

echo $number;
```