# php calculate the number of months for invoice delay between two dates

Tags: php

ok, I am trying to figure out how to create function to get the number of months delayed for invoice between two dates. I tried many hours, without success, i'm confused where to start...

Here is the formula:

FROM: **1/1/2020** TO: **10-02-2021**

```
Months 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (if not paid during this months, we count the number of month starting from the next month.)
count the number of months from the next month, from 6-2020 to 02-2021
result 9;
```

Again, we do the same:

```
Months: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
count the number of months from the next month, from 9-2020 to 02-2021
result 6;

7, 8, 9, 10, 11
count the number of months from the next month, from 12-2020 to 02-2021
result 3;

10, 11, 12, 01, 02
count the number of months from the next month, from 3-2021 to 02-2021 (not possible since date end in 10-02-2021
result 0;
```

so, at the end we count the number of months:

9 + 6 + 3 + 0 = 18

function should print "18".

thanks in advance!

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this logic achieves your desired result and is robust enough, but here goes.

You can use the results from the `$results` array in your function to calculate price.

```
<?php
$start = '2020-01-01';
$end = '2021-02-10';

$diff = monthDiff($start, $end) + 1; // OP uses 14 - counts 10 days feb as 1 month.
$offset = 5; // 5 months +15%
while($diff >= $offset) {
    $result[] = $diff - $offset;
    $offset += 3;
}


// source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416894/calculate-the-number-of-months-between-two-dates-in-php
function monthDiff($start, $end)
{
    $ts1 = strtotime($start);
    $ts2 = strtotime($end);

    $year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
    $year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

    $month1 = date('m', $ts1);
    $month2 = date('m', $ts2);

    $diff = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);
    return $diff;
}
```

`$result`:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => int 9
  1 => int 6
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 0

echo array_sum($result); // 18
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/X44bp)

Comment: thanks, i will try another date and tell you if works, also why is  not robust enough, i think while is very slow, btw is there a way to make it in excel please?